# JSON URL won't open in QGIS

Tags: qgis, error, json

When attempting to display the national chargepoint registry from the following URL:

http://chargepoints.dft.gov.uk/api/retrieve/registry/format/json

The following error returns:

http://chargepoints.dft.gov.uk/api/retrieve/registry/format/json is not a valid or recognized data source

I've tried following the instructions in another similar post without success: How to display geoJSON from an URL in a layer. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You must use a geoJSON file ([The GeoJSON Format Specification](http://www.geojson.org/geojson-spec.html)) and not a simple JSON file. Your example is not a GeoJSON file (no 'geometry' tag for example)

As example,  GitHub announced that you can now automatically view any GeoJSON files that may be in a repository inside an interactive map driven by MapBox technology (see my example [AAC.geojson](https://github.com/mlaloux/Aachen/blob/master/AAC.geojson))

And [GeoJSON on GitHub: Now What?](http://blog.geomusings.com/2013/06/18/geojson-on-github-now-what/) shows how to stream the GeoJSON file directly into QGIS:

[image]

[image]